# How to make a frame within a canvas take up the entire space?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make the `self.frame` widget fill the entire canvas. I'm new to canvas so I'm lost, this was my last failed attempt. I don't know what I'm missing. The code is executable, thank you very much for any help.

```
from tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, x=None, y=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, kwargs)


        self.lblframe = LabelFrame(self, text='Ajustes 0', bg='#2b313c', fg='green2', cursor='arrow')
        self.lblframe .pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True, padx=(10,5), pady=(0,10))

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.lblframe, borderwidth=0,  bg='red', width=x, height=100, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas .pack(side="left", fill='x', expand=True)

        self.scrolly = Scrollbar(self.lblframe, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrolly .pack(side="right", fill="y")


        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, bg='#2b313c', width=x, height=100)
        self.frame .pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.canvas .config(yscrollcommand=self.scrolly.set)
        self.canvas .bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all')))
        self.canvas .create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        #---loop----
        for i in range(8):
            label = Label(self.frame, text='number : %s' % i, font=('Calibri',9,'bold'), bg='#2b313c', fg='white', bd=0)
            label .grid(column=0, row=i, padx= (10,5), pady=(0,0), sticky='w')
      

root = Tk()
root .geometry('300x150')
frame = Example(root, 200, 100).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the frame inside the callback of `<Configure>` event of the canvas:

```py
class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, x=None, y=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.canvas .bind("<Configure>", self.on_canvas_resized)
        # save the frame item ID
        self.frame_id = self.canvas .create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")
        ...

    def on_canvas_resized(self, event):
        w = max(event.width, self.frame.winfo_width())
        h = max(event.height, self.frame.winfo_height())
        # resize the frame
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, width=w, height=h)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

...
```

Comment: @acw1668.Your solution did not even cross my mind, but it worked very well, thank you.